# Datagridview is not populating when submitting from winform search button

Tags: c#, winforms, search, stored-procedures, textbox

I currently have a C# winform that is compiling with zero errors and zero warnings:

This is my first go at a winform project:

Note: I have a similar project in ASPX that is working as expected

However this one needs to be in a winform.

I also need to start off with an empty datagrid because in the production environment the table we will be calling holds millions of rows.

(this cannot be a filter the datagrid type solution it would kill the server in production.)

the winform is super simple consisting of:

- a form: GetParentID
- a Text box: textBoxValueToSearch
- a button: BTN_SEARCH
- a data grid view: ParentIDOutput
- a connection string in app.config : RCPDEV (tested and working)

Problem: when I enter a value in the text box and click on the search button I'm expecting a single Parent_Container_Id to be returned in the data grid view. However clicking on the button does nothing.

I have tested the stored procedure code and this is working properly:

- Images:
- [get parent id stored procedure code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBYCY.png)
- [get parent id win form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDKCb.png)

---

**IN PROGRAM.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetParentID
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new GetParentID());
        }
    }
}
```

**IN GETPARENTID.DESIGNER.CS**

```
namespace GetParentID
{
    partial class GetParentID
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBoxValueToSearch = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.BTN_SEARCH = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.ParentIDOutput = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ParentIDOutput)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBoxValueToSearch
            // 
            this.textBoxValueToSearch.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 22);
            this.textBoxValueToSearch.Name = "textBoxValueToSearch";
            this.textBoxValueToSearch.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(268, 20);
            this.textBoxValueToSearch.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // BTN_SEARCH
            // 
            this.BTN_SEARCH.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(305, 20);
            this.BTN_SEARCH.Name = "BTN_SEARCH";
            this.BTN_SEARCH.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.BTN_SEARCH.TabIndex = 1;
            this.BTN_SEARCH.Text = "Search";
            this.BTN_SEARCH.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // ParentIDOutput
            // 
            this.ParentIDOutput.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.ParentIDOutput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 69);
            this.ParentIDOutput.Name = "ParentIDOutput";
            this.ParentIDOutput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(349, 67);
            this.ParentIDOutput.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // GetParentID
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(408, 299);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ParentIDOutput);
            this.Controls.Add(this.BTN_SEARCH);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBoxValueToSearch);
            this.Name = "GetParentID";
            this.Text = "GetParentID";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ParentIDOutput)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxValueToSearch;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button BTN_SEARCH;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView ParentIDOutput;
    }
}
```

**IN GETPARENTID.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetParentID
{
    public partial class GetParentID : Form
    {
        public GetParentID()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        BindingSource binder = new BindingSource();

        private void BTN_SEARCH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(RCPDEV)
            string constr;

            string containerIdValue = textBoxValueToSearch.Text;

            constr = Properties.Settings.Default.RCPDEV;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RFID_GET_CONTAINER_PARENT_ID", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CONTAINER_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = containerIdValue;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            adapter.Fill(dataTable);

            ParentIDOutput.DataSource = binder;

            binder.DataSource = dataTable;

            con.Close();

            //FillDataGridView();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what the heck I am doing wrong here

/ i have been pulling my hair out for the last 16 hours or so trying many different things and reading  whole lot of articles/tutorials/and help tickets to no avail.

I am at your mercy a to being able to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe event like [Control.Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click) to response any action by user on winform control.

```
// BTN_SEARCH
// 
this.BTN_SEARCH.Click += BTN_SEARCH_Click;
```

Or you can subscribe [MouseClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseclick).

You should look into [Control.Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control) list to find out what event fit into your situation.

You can subscribe event on Properties Window instead write code.

[image: Event List]

Comment: Thank you ibocon and jimi for the invaluable help, my form is working :) -- jimi the article was the missing piece -- now how do i upvote you??

Comment: @joopswip In order to update someone's answer, you need to earn some reputation. I guess this is your first post, I don't think you have enough reputation.

Comment: thank you ibocon .. now to earn some rep points :) -- and reciprocate and help others too.